# spring boot azure storage connection string error

Tags: spring, azure-storage

I use spring boot 2.0.2.
when I run the application spring boot in cmd with the mvn spring-boot: run command running smoothly, but when I export it to war and I run it on tomcat with the ROOT path I get the following error:

```
2018-08-22 17:21:17.312  INFO 10764 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.s.d.PriorityQueueEmailSchedulerService : Scheduled email Email{from=developerglob@gmail.com, to=[cisvapery@gmail.com], subject=Glob report buy point firetime \'2018-08-22T16:38+07:00\' and priority 1, body=, attachments=[report_buy_point pripurna bandung.csv], encoding=UTF-8} at UTC time [2018-08-22T16:38+07:00, 1] with priority {} with template
[WARN] AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storageAzureService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cloudStorageAccount'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.storage.StorageAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'azure.storage-com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.storage.StorageProperties': Could not bind properties to 'StorageProperties' : prefix=azure.storage, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'azure.storage' to com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.storage.StorageProperties
2018-08-22 17:21:18.183  INFO 10764 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.s.d.PriorityQueueEmailSchedulerService : Closing EmailScheduler
2018-08-22 17:21:18.185  INFO 10764 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.s.d.PriorityQueueEmailSchedulerService : Interrupting email scheduler consumer
Exception in thread "PriorityQueueEmailSchedulerService -- Consumer" org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2155)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:752)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:515)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:435)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:359)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:354)
        at it.ozimov.springboot.mail.service.defaultimpl.DefaultEmailService.send(DefaultEmailService.java:138)
        at it.ozimov.springboot.mail.service.defaultimpl.PriorityQueueEmailSchedulerService$Consumer.run(PriorityQueueEmailSchedulerService.java:443)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:620)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:547)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2150)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 24 more
2018-08-22 17:21:39.400  INFO 10764 --- [ost-startStop-1] m.s.d.PriorityQueueEmailSchedulerService : Closed EmailScheduler
[INFO] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-08-22 17:21:39.431  INFO 10764 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-08-22 17:21:39.437  INFO 10764 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[INFO] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener -

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[ERROR] LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'azure.storage' to com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.storage.StorageProperties:

    Property: azure.storage.connection-string
    Value: DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=globimage;AccountKey=j98PljOhAYdToMXHxFeLd5sC6afk1DMBeF8dfYETOYJU0j8AHp0Fkh3dgikoevByrkb2zCr4IwzST4HqjkBTUQ==
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:60:33
    Reason: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'connectionString'

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

even though the application properties are correct
application.properties:

```
#Server konfiguration port
server.port=8087
#spring.resources.static-locations[0]=file:src/main/resources/static/
#spring.resources.static-locations[1]=classpath:/static/

#JPA Konfiguration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://52.230.65.127;databaseName=globdbreview
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Develasas
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.legacy_limit_handler=true

#SQL Server JPA konfiguration
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.bridgetech.glob.model.SQLServerNativeDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#default JSP
#spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
#spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#Logging
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO

#Thymeleaf konfiguration
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

# Specify the Lucene Directory
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem

# Using the filesystem DirectoryProvider you also have to specify the default
# base directory for all indexes 
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = indexpath

#Smtp mail konfiguration
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=developerglobsa@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=@asdadsadsa
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.test-connection=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

#upload file
#spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50mb
#spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50mb

spring.mail.scheduler.enabled=true
spring.mail.scheduler.priorityLevels=5

spring.mail.scheduler.persistence.enabled=false
spring.mail.scheduler.persistence.redis.embedded=false
spring.mail.scheduler.persistence.redis.enabled=false

#azure storage
azure.storage.connection-string=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=globim;AccountKey=j98PljOhAYdToMXHxFeLd5sC6afk1DMBeF8dfYETOYJU0j8AHp0Fkh3dgik
```

StorageAzureService:

```
@Service
public class StorageAzureService {

    @Autowired
    private CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount;

    public static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http|https];EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=globimage;AccountKey=j98PljOhAYdToMXHxFeLd5sC6afk1DMBeF8dfYETOYJU0j8AHp0Fkh3dgikoevByrkb2zCr4IwzST4HqjkBTUQ==";

    final String containerName = "image";

    public StorageAzureService() {
//      try {
//          cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
//      } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void createContainerIfNotExists() {
        try {
            // Create a blob client.
            final CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            // Get a reference to a container. (Name must be lower case.)
            final CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
            // Create the container if it does not exist.
            if (container.createIfNotExists()) {
                System.out.println("True: " + containerName);
            } else {
                System.out.println("False: " + containerName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String uploadTextBlob(MultipartFile file, String fileName) {
        try {

            // Create a blob client.
            final CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            // Get a reference to a container. (Name must be lower case.)
            final CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
            // Get a blob reference for a text file.
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            // Upload some text into the blob.
            blob.upload(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize());
            System.out.println("success upload." + blob.getUri().toString());
            return blob.getUri().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void deleteTextBlob(String fileName) {
        try {
            if (fileName.startsWith("https://globimage.blob.core.windows.net/glob-images/")) {
                System.out.println("True: https://globimage.blob.core.windows.net/glob-images/");
                String fileNameImgGlob = fileName.substring(52);
                // Create a blob client.
                final CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
                // Get a reference to a container. (Name must be lower case.)
                final CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
                // Get a blob reference for a text file.
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(fileNameImgGlob);
                // Upload some text into the blob.
                if (blob.exists()) {
                    blob.deleteIfExists();
                    System.out.println("success delete." + blob.getUri().toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("file not found.");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteShareFile() {

        try {

            // Create the file client.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("sampleshare");

            if (share.deleteIfExists()) {
                System.out.println("sampleshare deleted");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void createDirectory() {

        try {
            // Create the file client.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("sampleshare");

            // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

            // Get a reference to the sampledir directory
            CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference("sampledir");

            if (sampleDir.createIfNotExists()) {
                System.out.println("sampledir created");
            } else {
                System.out.println("sampledir already exists");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    public void deleteDirectory() {
        try {
            // Create the file client.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("sampleshare");

            // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

            // Get a reference to the directory you want to delete
            CloudFileDirectory containerDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference("sampledir");

            // Delete the directory
            if (containerDir.deleteIfExists()) {
                System.out.println("Directory deleted");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void listFilesAndDirectories() {
        try {
            // Create the file client.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference(containerName);
            // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

            for (ListFileItem fileItem : rootDir.listFilesAndDirectories()) {
                System.out.println(fileItem.getUri());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void uploadFile() {
        try {
            // Create the file client.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("share-images");

            if (share.createIfNotExists()) {
                System.out.println("New share created");
            }

            // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

            // Define the path to a local file.
            final String filePath = "D:\\uploads\\my.jpg";

            CloudFile cloudFile = rootDir.getFileReference("my.jpg");
            cloudFile.uploadFromFile(filePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void downloadFile() {
        try {
            // Create the file client.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("sampleshare");

            // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

            // Get a reference to the directory that contains the file
            CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference("sampledir");

            // Get a reference to the file you want to download
            CloudFile file = sampleDir.getFileReference("SampleFile.txt");

            // Write the contents of the file to the console.
            System.out.println(file.downloadText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void deleteFile2() {
        try {
            // Create the file client.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("sampleshare");

            // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

            // Get a reference to the directory where the file to be deleted is in
            CloudFileDirectory containerDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference("sampledir");

            String filename = "SampleFile.txt";
            CloudFile file;

            file = containerDir.getFileReference(filename);
            if (file.deleteIfExists()) {
                System.out.println(filename + " was deleted");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

}
```

GlobApplication:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.bridgetech.glob")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEmailTools
public class GlobApplication
//implements ApplicationContextAware
{

    @Autowired
    EmailSenderService emailSenderService;
//  
//  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GlobApplication.class, args);
    }

//  @Override
//  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
//      this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
//  }
//
    @PostConstruct
    public void sendEmail() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InterruptedException, CannotSendEmailException, URISyntaxException {
        emailSenderService.scheduleSixEmails(1);

//      close();
    }

//  private void close() {
//      TimerTask shutdownTask = new TimerTask() {
//          @Override
//          public void run() {
//              ((AbstractApplicationContext) applicationContext).close();
//          }
//      };
//      Timer shutdownTimer = new Timer();
//      shutdownTimer.schedule(shutdownTask, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(20));
//  }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bridgetech</groupId>
    <artifactId>glob</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>glob</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.0.4</azure.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId> 
            <scope>runtime</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icegreen</groupId>
            <artifactId>greenmail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- bootstrap and jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-freemarker-email</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

How do I fix this problem, thank you

Comment: what should i edit

Comment: application.properties:
#azure storage
azure.storage.connection-string=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=glob;AccountKey=j98PljOhAYdToMXHxFeLd5sC6afk1DMBeF8dfYETOYJU0j8AHp0Fkh3dgikoevByrkb2zCr4IwzST

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding the following mandatory attributes in your application.properties.

```
azure.storage.accountName = 
azure.storage.accountKey =
```

If you are using the following dependency in your project, you need to include the above properties.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

For additional fields which are optional, please go through below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-storage